# Swift - Is there a way to wake up my app at a certain time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm currently trying to make an alarm clock app, and I have a problem, because I need to wake up the app if it's closed when the alarm time is up, and then do some things inside my app, before sending a notification. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I've been thinking of scheduling a local notification to wake up the app, but as I understand it, the user has to interact with it for that to happen, which isn't what I want. I've been looking at background fetch, but if I'm correct, you can't explicitly tell the app when to do a background fetch. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: That's what background modes are for. Take a look over that!

Comment: Right, but like I said, I don't know of a background mode that can wake my app up at a certain time, even when it's closed. I know I can do it by location, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Silent notifications are still part of background modes, and that's exactly ehat they're for!

Comment: Hey Did you figure out how to wake up the app at a certain time ? Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a silent notification.
You can find a good description [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8).